# How to update object element in array with lowest possible sequence available for object element?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I am validating and updating name property of object in object array with lowest available sequence number.

```
    var instances = [
          {
            "Name": "Packer-Builder-01",
            "InstanceId": "i-03802c9af5ca28c15"
          },
          {
            "Name": "Packer-Builder",
            "InstanceId": "i-03802c9af5ca25z17"
          },
          {
            "Name": "Packer-Builder",
            "InstanceId": "i-03802c9af5ca38l21"
          },
          {
            "Name": "Packer-Builder-03",
            "InstanceId": "i-0f9c76032682211e8"
          }
        ]
```

Should be as;

```
 instances =   [
          {
            "Name": "Packer-Builder-01",
            "InstanceId": "i-03802c9af5ca28c15"
          },
          {
            "Name": "Packer-Builder-02",
            "InstanceId": "i-03802c9af5ca25z17"
          },
          {
            "Name": "Packer-Builder-04",
            "InstanceId": "i-03802c9af5ca38l21"
          },
          {
            "Name": "Packer-Builder-03",
            "InstanceId": "i-0f9c76032682211e8"
          }
        ]
```

I am doing by this creating two arrays from object arrays and then comparing these by using for each loop. Solution is working, but I feel it is too much code for this requirement. Please suggest some approach ?

Answer (score 2):

You could collect all used numbers in a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and take a new unused value for the numbering.

```js
var instances = [{ Name: "Packer-Builder-01", InstanceId: "i-03802c9af5ca28c15" }, { Name: "Packer-Builder", InstanceId: "i-03802c9af5ca25z17" }, { Name: "Packer-Builder", InstanceId: "i-03802c9af5ca38l21" }, { Name: "Packer-Builder-03", InstanceId: "i-0f9c76032682211e8" }],
    values = new Set(instances.map(({ Name }) => +Name.match(/\d{2}$/)));

instances.forEach((i => o => {
    if (/\d{2}$/.test(o.Name)) return;
    while (values.has(i)) i++;
    o.Name += '-' + i.toString().padStart(2, '0');
    i++;
})(1));

console.log(instances);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank for help, this exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @ZAM, great. please have a look here, to: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you will need to create a mapped array for each and every one of the keys, and then update the name property with an help function that add the suffix.

```
var instances = {Name: {...}, InstanceId: {...}};
Object.keys(instances).map(name => name).forEach((k) => {
    instances[k].name = addSuffixIfNotExist(instances[k].name, k);
});

function addSuffixIfNotExist(name, index) {
    // code
}
```